# In Magento 2 how can I retrieve a container from layout?

Tags: magento2, magento-layout-xml

How can I retrieve a container from the layout programmatically?

I would like to be able to do something like the following...

```
$container = $layout->getContainer('name');
$container->setAttribute('htmlClass', 'class');
```

Answer (score 3):

So I'll be that guy, try your best not to use the object manager directly. [To use or not to use the ObjectManager directly?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->renderNonCachedElement('top-right-wrapper'); ?>
-or-
<?= $this->getLayout()->renderNonCachedElement('top-right-wrapper'); ?>
```

Both above will work but using $this is discouraged. [Magento 2 Templates: Use `$block` or `$this`?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103096/magento-2-templates-use-block-or-this)

Answer (score 1):

With little debugging in core I have found that there is a method which
returns any container,block or UIcomponent html using name as parameter.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$layoutObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Layout');
$html = $layoutObj->renderNonCachedElement('top-right-wrapper');
echo $html;
```

* Replace top-right-wrapper with your block,container or UIcomponent name.